# CSS: problem with Toggle Switch. How to render the behavior of an input checkbox for the whole Toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, checkbox

I am developing a web application (using AngularJS) and I need to create a **Toggle Switch**.
The guides on the web don't seem difficult, and I followed the one from W3C: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

In this guide everything is ok: I can click wherever I want within the Toggle Switch area and it behaves as it should.
Behind it, obviously, there must be a `checkbox` type input.

Unfortunately, this does not happen in my application. This is my code (I used `<div>` instead `<label>` because label already have a proper style):

```
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}


.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
 
<div class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, this is the exact same W3C code (except that I don't obscure the input, otherwise nothing would happen in my case!). Unfortunately what happens is the following thing:

[image]
[image]

The style is perfect, but the behavior is only right by clicking in the small left corner (which would be the `input checkbox` that was purposely not obscured!). If I make the checkbox input invisible as suggested by the W3C, I can no longer click in that corner and nothing happens!

I don't understand how to make the `input checkbox` invisible but still extend its behavior to the whole Toggle Switch! Where am I wrong?

Comment: _“Where am I wrong?”_ - in replacing an element that had a very specific purpose, when it comes to form fields (`label`), with one that has no such specific purpose at all (`div`).

Comment: _“because label already have a proper style”_ - the choice of what the correct HTML element is for a given purpose, should _never_ rely on aspects like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `<label>` instead